# error on hbase table instance creation after upgrading java client to 2.2.2

Tags: java, hbase

An application that accesses hbase is producing an error on attempting to create an instance of an hbase table. This used to work fine but the hbase server was upgraded and subsequently I was forced to update the java client.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/lang3/NotImplementedException
at 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation$2.build(ConnectionImplementation.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection.getTable(Connection.java:106)
at 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getTable(ConnectionImplementation.java:366)
```

The above error occurs on the following line:

```
hTable_Test = conn.getTable(TableName.valueOf("test:test_messages"));
```

I don't understand what the issue is. Can someone please help verify what this error means?

Answer (score 1):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that at runtime you don't have java class which was available at compile time.
`org/apache/commons/lang3/NotImplementedException` comes with `group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: 'some version'`
Can you check if you have this jar file in your execution environment?

Comment: I added the dependency and downloaded the jar; still the same issue. Thanks